# How to compare float variables using strict inequality?

Tags: optimization, cplex

I'm trying to implement a maximize problem. In one part I am trying to compare a float to a dvar float for which I get the Error "The operator >(float, dvar float) is not available in the context of CPLEX." Using >= works, but I get wrong results. Is there any way to work around the error?

```
float price[D][A] = ...;
float volaforecast[D] = ...;
dvar float vola;
dvar int change[D][A];

maximize sum(d in D, a in A)(price[d][a] * change[d][a]);

subject to {
    forall(d in D: d > 1) {
        ( volaforecast[d] <= vola && 
          volaforecast[d-1] > vola && 
          change[d]["a"] == 0
        ) || (
          volaforecast[d] > vola && 
          volaforecast[d-1] <= vola && 
          change[d]["a"] == 1
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use strict inequalities between cplex variables and constants or other variables because that would make the model not linear. You need to use something like var >= (value + epsilon) for some suitably small epsilon

Comment: Hi Tim! You may want to put your comment as an answer instead: it *is* a perfectly valid answer that the OP could accept, and that we could up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim mentioned in his comment, you should use `var >= value + epsilon`.  Strict inequality doesn't fit the Linear Programming paradigm that CPLEX uses.